# WSPBuilder: How to create a deployment package to deploy multiple .dlls and .wsps?

Tags: deployment, wspbuilder

I'm using WSPBuilder and it is very helpful. However, it is hard to understand the features of WSPBuilder because of its missing manual. I have to create a solution file to deploy "Return of SmartPart" (.wsp file), "Application Template Core" (.wsp file) and also "AJAX Extensions" (.dll files) so I won't have to edit the web.config to mark them safe controls.

Please, suggest how?

Answer (score 2):

Those WSP files are existing files, I don't think you can bring them into another WSP. CodePlex has a WSP for installing AJAX to a SharePoint site. Also, CodePlex has a SharePoint Solution Installer which you can use to automate, via a wizard, the installation of WSP files.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the "Ajax Extensions" are they a project dependency, or is it a stand alone install/deployment item?

If it is a project dependency you can deploy it to the bin as part of your solution file.